# Filtering a result set to show or hide specific result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using "SELECT [Users],[Stars] FROM [Table]", here is an example result set returned:

```
<table border="1">
  <th>Users</th>
  <th>Stars</th>
  <tr>
     <td>Admin</td><td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Worker</td><td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Student</td><td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How would I show the Admin ONLY if he has more than 3 stars and not be a part of the result set if it is 3 stars or less?

My best guess is a CASE WHEN statement but would it go in the SELECT or a WHERE clause?

I'm still quite new to development and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses. Please up vote my question as I would love to up vote answers but don't have 15 rep yet. Me == noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should cover it just using a Where clause

```
SELECT
    [Users],
    [Stars]
FROM
    [Table]
WHERE
    [Users] != 'Admin'
    OR [Stars] > 3
```

Comment: This would Admin to never be selected and the selections or only be greater than 3 stars.

Comment: @StormMagnus  you don't get how the `OR` works then.. Either condition can be met to include the record..  so it can either not be an ADMIN or it can have more than 3 stars

Comment: @StormMagnus here is an example of how OR works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19a7e4/1

Comment: Sorry I had poor wording in my response @JamieD77, I meant the result set had to show 'Admin' ONLY if it had over 3 stars. All the rest can be a part of it regardless of the number of stars.

Comment: @Bacon Bits and you both had correct answers... but I learned something new from your answer. I forgot only one of the conditions need to be true, for some reason when I looked at it, I thought it would not evaluate the second condition upon failure of the first. I need coffee.

Answer (score 2):

This will exclude any user Admin with stars less than 3:

```
SELECT [Users],[Stars] 
FROM [Table]
WHERE NOT ([Users] = 'Admin' AND [Stars] <= 3)
```

Comment: This is it Bacon Bits... and I love the name. :)

Comment: @StormMagnus  just so you know.. this will include Admins with a 3 star rating..   it should be `[Stars] <= 3` or `[Stars] < 4`

Comment: True. Yes, I caught that @JamieD77 but it was just a small thing. The real thing I'm working on is much more complex and I watered it down to this question for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the WHERE clause is for.

```
SELECT [Users],[Stars] FROM [Table]
WHERE Stars > 3
```

Comment: This does not help with choosing 'admin' only with 3 stars, just everybody with 3 stars.